# DDD and constructor explosion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

I'm practicing DDD with ASP.NET MVC and come to a situation where my controllers have many dependencies on different services and repositories, and testing becomes very tedious.

In general, I have a service or repository for each aggregate root. Consider a page which will list a **customer**, along with it's **orders** and a dropdown of different **packages** and **sellers**. All of those types are aggregate roots. For this to work, I need a **CustomerService**, **OrderService**, **PackageRepository** and a **UserRepository**. Like this:

```
public class OrderController {
    public OrderController(Customerservice customerService, 
      OrderService orderService, Repository<Package> packageRepository, 
      Repository<User> userRepository) 
    {
        _customerService = customerService
        ..
    }
}
```

Imagine the number of dependencies and constructor parameters required to render a more complex view.

Maybe I'm approaching my service layer wrong; I could have a CustomerService which takes care of all this, but my service constructor will then explode. I think I'm violating SRP too much.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: @jfar It might not be wrong, but it's not handy. Some of my controllers require 8-9 dependencies and that does not feel right.

Comment: If your screen requires data from 8-9 services than you need 8-9 dependencies.  I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Absolutely, but maybe theres a more flexible way of getting my dependencies? For example, i could have a method like `ViewData.Requires<Package>("Packages").SelectList()` to get my dropdowns. That could use my IoC to load all packages from my package repository, no need for a constructor dependency.

Answer (score 4):

> I think I'm violating SRP too much.

Bingo.

I find that using a command processing layer makes my applications architecture cleaner and more consistent.

Basically, each service method becomes a command handler class (and the method parameters become a command class), and every query is also its own class.

This won't actually reduce your dependencies - your query will likely still require those same couple of services and repositories to provide the correct data; however, when using an IoC framework like Ninject or Spring it won't matter because they will inject what is needed up the whole chain - and testing should be much easier as a dependency on a specific query is easier to fill and test than a dependency on a service class with many marginally related methods.

Also, now the relationship between the Controller and its dependencies is clear, logic has been removed from the Controller, and the query and command classes are more focused on their individual responsibilities.

Yes, this does cause a bit of an explosion of classes and files.  Employing proper Object Oriented Programming will tend to do that.  But, frankly, what's easier to find/organize/manage - a function in a file of dozens of other semi-related functions or a single file in a directory of dozens of semi-related files.  I think that latter hands down.

[Code Better had a blog post recently](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2011/04/27/why-use-the-command-processor-pattern-in-the-service-layer/) that nearly matches my preferred way of organizing controllers and commands in an MVC app.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I actually use command processing for my CUD scenarios. However, this does not help with all data that's needed to display my views. Or am I missing something? Edit: i'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @alexn: Create a class to represent your query.  This helps some, but ultimately if you really need several services and several repositories to compile all the data you just can't get rid of the dependencies.  There's no magic to apply here.  The only option is to materialize view data earlier - that is, create tables or objects in a KV store that get populated with the CUD happens (usually by using events).  Are you familiar with CQRS?  If not, you should read up.

Comment: I have looked at CQRS but i'm having a hard time to really get it. Maybe i should play with it some more.

Comment: Keep it simple, it doesn't have to mean event sourcing and distributed message buses.  Simply creating a class that represents a single query and using that is CQRS. Instead of 2 services and 2 repos injected into the controller and piecing together all that data in the action method - do that in the query class.

Comment: The query class would still need the same dependencies, but if you're using an IoC component it will make your controller constructor signatures simpler.  And later you could potentially re-implement the query classes to either avoid the rigamarole of using many services and repositories and going straight to the DB - whether through a micro ORM or to a pre-materialized view table.  In essence, what I'm recommending is refactoring the query logic from your action method into a class that has one reponsibility - getting the data and returning a view model ready for your view.

Comment: Sorry, I was going quick while code was compiling.  I meant to upvote.  Down with Repository/Service patterns!

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I agree that query objects is a clean solution which i'm going to try out. A nice thing is that my query objects can use my NHibernates ISession directly. How do you recommend that i instantiate my query objects? I mean, i need to get them from somewhere.

Comment: @jfar I completely agree with you on that. It seems that it's just complicating things.

Comment: @alexn - Yeah, usually controller actions are tied to a single query, especially display ones.  I'd rather reference a single query class which contains all the logic for that single query, duplicated if it must, than these monster service controller layers where each action method uses 1% of the available logic.

Comment: @alexn: instantiate the query objects with your IoC. Inject them into the controller constructor.

Comment: @qes that's an idea. Maybe it would be nice to combine query objects with controller less actions, like Jeremy Skinner explained at http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/06/20/controllerless-actions-with-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

Well you can solve this issue easily by using the `RenderAction`. Just create separate controllers or introduce child actions in those controllers. Now in the main view call render actions with the required parameters. This will give you a nice composite view.

Comment: Wouldn't that impact the performance pretty much? I havent done any specific profiling on RenderAction but i've heard that it's not very performant.

Comment: @alexn I have used the RenderAction in cases you have mentioned and I do not find any issue with performance, the number of render action usually ranged from 1-8. Unless you are doing something crazy like rendering list of records in a loop, I am sure you will not find much of a difference.

Though it is true behind the scene RenderAction executes almost the same codes as the regular request, yet I will pick it as it makes my code more modular and clean.

Comment: @alexn The only argument I have heard regarding the RenderAction is that it is violation of Mvc Principle as in this case the view is calling back the controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your anwsers. As long as it provides a clean way to structure my code, it does not realy bother me that it's a violation of strict MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a service for this scenario to return a view model for you? That way you only have one dependency in the controller although your service may have the separate dependencies

Answer (score 0):

the book dependency injection in .net suggests introducing "facade services" where you'd group related services together then inject the facade instead if you feel like you have too many constructor parameters.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** I finally had some available time, so I ended up finally creating an implementation for what I was talking about in my post below.  My implementation is:

```
public class WindsorServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    protected IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorServiceFactory(IWindsorContainer windsorContainer)
    {
        _container = windsorContainer;
    }

    public ServiceType GetService<ServiceType>() where ServiceType : class
    {
        // Use windsor to resolve the service class.  If the dependency can't be resolved throw an exception
        try { return _container.Resolve<ServiceType>(); }
        catch (ComponentNotFoundException) { throw new ServiceNotFoundException(typeof(ServiceType)); }
    }
}
```

All that is needed now is to pass my `IServiceFactory` into my controller constructors, and I am now able to keep my constructors clean while still allowing easy (and flexible) unit tests.  More details can be found at my blog [blog](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/keeping-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors-clean-in-a-dependency-injection-world/) if you are interested.

---

I have noticed the same issue creeping up in my MVC app, and your question got me thinking of how I want to handle this.  As I'm using a command and query approach (where each action or query is a separate service class) my controllers are already getting out of hand, and will probably be even worse later on.

After thinking about this I think the route I am going to look at going is to create a `SerivceFactory` class, which would look like:

```
public class ServiceFactory
{
    public ServiceFactory( UserService userService, CustomerService customerService, etc...)
    {
        // Code to set private service references here
    }

    public T GetService<T>(Type serviceType) where T : IService
    {
        // Determine if serviceType is a valid service type, 
        //  and return the instantiated version of that service class
        //   otherwise throw error
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote this up in Notepad++ off hand so I am pretty sure I got the generics part of the `GetService` method syntactically wrong , but that's the general idea.  So then your controller will end up looking like this:

```
public class OrderController {
    public OrderController(ServiceFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }
}
```

You would then have IoC instantiate your `ServiceFactory` instance, and everything should work as expected.

The good part about this is that if you realize that you have to use the `ProductService` class in your controller, you don't have to mess with controller's constructor at all, you only have to just call `_factory.GetService()` for your intended service in the action method.

Finally, this approach allows you to still mock services out (one of the big reasons for using IoC and passing them straight into the controller's constructor) by just creating a new `ServiceFactory` in your test code with the mocked services passed in (the rest left as null).

I think this will keep a good balance out the best world of flexibility and testability, and keeps service instantiation in one spot.

After typing this all out I'm actually excited to go home and implement this in my app :)

Comment: I know this answer is going on a decade old but this answer is essentially discussing/implementing a ServiceLocator which doesn't solve the problem at all (and introduces another) and just propagates the problem along either through an IoC Container or _another_ class' constructor having a ton of dependencies. Also, I'd like to mention that passing around containers is also very bad as containers should follow RRR (Register, Resolve, Release).

Comment: As the original creator of this answer, I Agree.  It's amazing how bad some of the "good ideas" i had a decade ago have aged :).  I have moved away from this a looong time ago and realized the service locator/factory pattern is really bad.